# bundle exec rake assets:precompile take incredible time with docker and rails_admin

Tags: docker, ruby-on-rails-5, rake, rails-admin, rake-task

How to speed up the rake assets process (`rake assets:precompile`) when building a docker rails image with `rails_admin` ?

**Issue :**

I'm trying to build a docker image of a rails application (below the Dockerfile), but the step `RUN bundle exec rake assets:precompile` hangs and took enormous time, up to 20 minutes and sometime docker stops the image build due to execution timeout. I think it is related to `rails_admin`, so i disabled it and the image was build without waiting all this time. When the rails_admin is enabled, the log of docker indicates that the task generate my own assets then it is blocked for a considerable time before displaying the assets of rails_admin and continue the build. 
Should i build the assets before running the build process of there's something related to rails_admin that should be fixed  ?

**Os / Docker**

- Os : Windows 10
- Docker : Version 18.03.1-ce-win65

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ruby:2.3.3

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
# Set an environment variable where the Rails app is installed to inside of Docker image
ENV RAILS_ROOT /var/www/unk-web-app

RUN mkdir -p $RAILS_ROOT
# Set working directory
WORKDIR $RAILS_ROOT
# Setting env up
#ENV RAILS_ENV='production'
#ENV RACK_ENV='production'
# Adding gems
COPY Gemfile Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
# https://stephencodes.com/upgrading-ruby-dockerfiles-to-use-bundler-2-0-1/
ENV BUNDLER_VERSION 2.0.2
#set the version in Gemfile

RUN bundle install --jobs 20 --retry 5 --without development test
# Adding project files
COPY . .

# get the database url from docker image building
ARG DATABASE_URI
ARG RAILS_ENV

# Set env
ENV DOCKER 1


RUN bundle exec rake db:migrate

RUN bundle exec rake assets:precompile

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["bundle", "exec", "puma", "-C", "config/puma.rb"]
```

Comment: Could you edit it in the form of a question?

Comment: @GuillermoSiliceoTrueba the title or the description ?

Comment: The description please. Thanks

Comment: @GuillermoSiliceoTrueba, is it ok for the new edit ? thanks.

Comment: @HoussemFat what is your host OS? It is known that Docker sometimes has troubles on macOS.

Comment: @mutantkeyboard i forgot to mention, i'm on Windows 10 but the assets pipeline is working fine without rails_admin.